# Jest test failing when i try to set a state

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am trying to write some tests for a component i have written. It is a date/time component where by when you set a date from a calender, it sets the date to its local state, and then moves to a time selection component.

While this all works perfectly as a component, i cant seem to get th tests to pass. Currently having a problem with setting state in a jest test.

The test is as follows:

```
it('Time picker should appear', () => {
  const navigation = {
    navigate: jest.fn(),
  };
  const output = shallow(<DateTimePicker navigation={navigation} />);
  const date = new Date('January 31 2018 12:30');
  output.setState({selectedDate: date});
  expect(output).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

code of component is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { injectIntl, FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import { DatePicker }  from '../../components/DatePicker';
import TimePicker from '../../components/TimePicker';
import Text from '../../components/Text';
import { propTypes } from './prop-types';
import styles from './styles';

export class DateTimePicker extends React.Component {

  state = {
    selectedDate: '',
  }

  confirmDateAndTime = (hours, minutes) => {
    const { selectedDate } = this.state;
    const date = new Date(selectedDate);
    date.setHours(hours);
    date.setMinutes(minutes);
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    /**
     * navigate back to booking flight edit with the updated
     * date selection.
     */
    navigation.navigate('BookingFlightEdit', date);
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedDate } = this.state;
    /**
     * if date has been selected - move onto the time selection
     */
    if(selectedDate.length>0) {
      return (
        <View>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.title} type="h1">
              <FormattedMessage
                defaultMessage="Select Time"
                id="date_time_picker.select_time"
              />
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.time}>
            <TimePicker
              testID='time-button'
              onPress={(hh,mm) => this.confirmDateAndTime(hh, mm)}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.title} type="h1">
          <FormattedMessage
            defaultMessage="Select Date"
            id="date_time_picker.select_date"
          />
        </Text>
        <DatePicker
          testID = 'date-button'
          onDayPress={(date) => this.setState({selectedDate: date.dateString})}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

DateTimePicker.propTypes = propTypes;

export default injectIntl(DateTimePicker);
```

however, whenever i run the test,  iget the following error;

> ```
> ShallowWrapper::setState() can only be called on class components
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Your class is wrapped by `injectIntl`. This is the direct cause of the error you're encountering, as the internals of `injectIntl` are not a class. You will want to test an instance of your `DateTimePicker` class that is not wrapped by this Higher-Order component. You can do this by calling `.dive()` on the Enzyme wrapper.

```
it('Time picker should appear', () => {
  const navigation = {
    navigate: jest.fn(),
  };
  const output = shallow(<DateTimePicker navigation={navigation} />);
  const date = new Date('January 31 2018 12:30');
  const datePicker = output.dive();
  datePicker.setState({selectedDate: date});
  expect(datePicker).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```